# Jetty How to re-deploy war

Tags: java, jetty, war, embedded-jetty

Now I have read Jetty docs http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Setting_a_Web_Application_Context .

But there are no info about how to make code with hot re-deploy of the war file with scanInterval.

It must re-deploy war file if it changed.

How to code this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hot deploying simple application in jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376596/hot-deploying-simple-application-in-jetty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hot deploy you need to deploy the webapp with the deployment manager and the webapp or context provider.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Hot_Deployment

the xml shown there (and in the distribution in the jetty-deploy.xml and jetty-webapps.xml) can be converted to java simply

Comment: Yes, I have see it. But I don't want to use XML configs. Is it possible to define this logic in the Java code? As Property or by call some function, like ****.setInterval(7)? :)

Comment: jetty xml can be directly mapped to java code, see: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax#Basic_Example

Comment: And how to make this code: `<New id="DeploymentManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager"><Arg>deployed</Arg>
            <Arg>starting</Arg>
            <Arg>customise</Arg>`? On the code `DeploymentManager qqq;
            qqq = new DeploymentManager("deployed", "starting", "customise");` is errors...