# How to re-deploy a .war file with Jetty and Clojure?

Tags: clojure, jetty

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/ddellacosta/Clojure-under-Jetty-and-Apache#setting-up-jetty-with-apache-httpd) to deploy my `web_test` app; when I enter `http://0.0.0.0:8080/web_test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone/` on the browser I see a "hello world" displayed . . . but that's not what I have in `core.clj` file! I have "Hello World; it works!"

I did everything over, I created a new .war file, and I ran Jetty again with

```
$ java -jar start.jar
```

but I see the same wrong "hello world"

What am I doing wrong?

---

As I was posting [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092786/jetty-how-to-re-deploy-war) came up, so do I need to change the configure file to redeploy? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial looks pretty far out of date.

The easiest way to test your ring app is to use lein ring server, which will start an embedded jetty (usually port 3000), and then automatically reload code as you make changes to your Clojure files. It's very lightweight and quite nice.

This tutorial is more up to date. http://zaiste.net/2013/05/getting_started_with_clojure_web_apps/

Comment: Yes, `lein ring server` works fine and I see my correct page displayed on the browser. But I was asking about Jetty. How do I redeploy the .war file with Jetty. Let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: I reread your answer; so I don't need to run `$ java -jar start.jar` after updating the clojure files?

Comment: If you follow the tutorial, and you're running in dev mode (lein ring server), then you just change your clojure file and (assuming it compiles) refresh your browser. The leiningen plugin will notice the change and recompile the file and then process the request.